# growattServer 1.4.0 - function api.dashboard_data() timespan argument

Tags: python, enums, parameter-passing

Im having issues understand what arguments to send to the [growattServer 1.4.0](https://github.com/indykoning/PyPi_GrowattServer) function api.dashboard_data()

The function looks like

```
def dashboard_data(self, plant_id, timespan=Timespan.hour, date=None):
```

```
class Timespan(IntEnum):
    hour = 0
    day = 1
    month = 2
```

If I try

```
print(api.dashboard_data('INVERTERID',timespan=0,date='2023-02-01'))
```

I get:

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'in': 'int' and 'EnumType'*

I get the same error if I do

```
print(api.dashboard_data('INVERTERID',0,date='2023-02-01'))
```

I do not understand what arguments to pass for the timespan function and would appricate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

For `timespan` you are passing in a `0` -- in both attempts; includeing the parameter name makes no difference.

Try:

print(api.dashboard_data('INVERTERID', Timespan.hour, date='2023-02-01')

Questions for you:

- can `plant_id` be a string?
- can `date` be a string?  Or should it be a `datetime.date`?

Comment: `print(api.dashboard_data('INVERTERID',Timespan.hour,date='2023-02-11'))` results in *NameError: name 'Timespan' is not defined*. Yes, both `plant_id` and `date` should be a string.

Comment: @PerRydholm: You need to import `Timespan` from the module it lives in, or include the module name.  For example, if `Timespan` is in the `api` module: `api.dashboard_data(..., api.Timespan.hour, ...)`.

Comment: that I have done already: `import growattServer`

Comment: @PerRydholm: Did you use `growattServer.Timespan.hour`?